# How do I remote access mysql server from any host?

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I followed [78246](https://serverfault.com/questions/78246/remote-mysql-server)
When I do

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* for 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';  
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'for 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1
```

How do I make it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be to, not for.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Comment: +1, I hate when I've got an answer typed in and I get the "Load new answers?" box right as I'm about to post.

Comment: I thought someone was going to beat me to answering this one :)